# Get Specific Value from Multidimensional Associative JSON

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get a specific value from a JSON response and am having trouble figuring out how to target it. I can loop through it but I want to only output a single value based on the key as the response is dynamic and not always guaranteed to have the same output.

I have converted the JSON response to an array and here is an example of what I have at this point:

```
Array (
     [0] => Array (
         [rel] => advertisements
         [href] => https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/advertisements
     )
     [1] => Array (
         [rel] => active_season_team
         [href] => https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/teams
     )
     [2] => Array (
         [rel] => assignments
         [href] => https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/assignments
     )
     [3] => Array (
         [rel] => availabilities
         [href] => https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/availabilities
     ) 
)
```

I need to be able to echo the "href" value by the key "rel". I have tried:

```
foreach($links as $key => $value) {
  echo $key['advertisements'];
}
```

But need a way to say $links as $key->rel = $value->http (thats the logic I can come up with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) on the `rel` column (extracted using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)) to find the key of a matching value (e.g. `advertisements`). If it exists, you can then access the value directly:

```
if(($key = array_search('advertisements', array_column($links, 'rel'))) !== false) {
    echo $links[$key]['href'];
}
```

Output

```
https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/advertisements
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YCMNU)

For more flexibility, you could write this as a function:

```
function get_link($links, $cat) {
    if(($key = array_search($cat, array_column($links, 'rel'))) !== false) {
        return $links[$key]['href'];
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}

echo get_link($links, 'active_season_team');
```

Output:

```
https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/teams
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bmQ6d)

Comment: This works! So lets say I want to get several different items from this array, is there a  quicker way to do something like `echo $links['advertisements'];` just to keep things clean and simple? That's what I am really hoping to figure out.

Comment: @RiotAct you could use a function - see for example my edit. The function returns an empty string for not found, but you could return `false` or anything else suitable to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your requirements but as per syntax, In your case key will be index of array you can get data as below:

```
foreach($links as $link){
  echo $link['rel'].' = '.$link['href'];
}
```

Comment: This just loops through all of them. I want to be able to get a single specific 'href' by specifying the 'rel'